# Best way to announce a new application or addon for use with Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, userscript, addon

I recently implemented an application for Stack Overflow. It's a [Chrome extension](http://rainsoft.io/clipboardy-chrome-extension/) called Clipboardy, which enables easy copying the source code from posts to the clipboard with a single button click. The source code for Clipboardy is in [a repository of mine on GitHub](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy).

What is the best and correct way to let the Stack Overflow community know about these kind of applications/addons?

- Post a question with the program description on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?
- Post a question with the program description on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)?
- Or, is there a special place for this sort of thing?

Comment: If someone interested, posted here: http://stackapps.com/questions/6753/clipboardy-chrome-extension-to-copy-posted-source-to-clipboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Create a question on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) describing your application or script

One of the functions of the Stack Apps site is to have questions announcing the availability of applications and scripts which work with Stack Exchange. In other words, the site exists to be available for what you want. So, it's perfectly valid to post your app on Stack Apps.

#### Use either the [app](https://stackapps.com/tags/app/info) or [script](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) tag on your Stack Apps question.

##### The [app](https://stackapps.com/tags/app/info) tag

The [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app) tag is for:

> Use this ONLY to list or announce your application; and ONLY if that application either uses the Stack Exchange API or works on any of the Stack Exchange websites. See stackapps.com/q/7/ for more information.

> These questions are encouraged to follow the format mentioned in ["How do I list my app here?"](http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-on-stack-apps)

##### The [script](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) tag

In your case, you have a Chrome extension, so it should be tagged with the [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script) tag, as the tag tells you:

> Use this tag to post a userscript that operates on Stack Exchange sites and/or uses the Stack Exchange API.  For questions about user scripting and Stack Exchange, or its API, use the [scripts] tag instead.  Scripts are usually JavaScript and usually browser extensions/userscripts.  For other tools, the [app] tag may be more appropriate.

(Emphased myself)

How the question should be written, you can see by following  https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=script. That's a placeholder, you edit what you need, remove what you don't need, and click "post".